# Custom User Store Manager not recognized (WSOIS 5.3)

Tags: java, jdbc, wso2, osgi-bundle, wso2-identity-server

I've written a custom User Store Manager to interface WSO2 to a database managed by ASP.Net's Simple Membership Provider. My main issue is that SMP uses PBKDF2 for password hashing and the standard JDBC User Store doesn't seem to support that.

I basically used https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Writing+a+Custom+User+Store+Manager as a template, as the example implements a different password hashing algo, which is exactly my use case.

You can find my POC implementation here: [github project wso2_custom_userstore](https://github.com/SunTsu/wso2_custom_userstore) I built a jar, put it into the dropins directory and restarted the server. The server complained about lack of bundle headers, but that's it. When adding a new user store there's only the standard stores, nothing more. I then configured a JDBC user store and changed the class to the one I wrote. The only effect I saw was that my previously configured User Store had vanished. I tried putting the .jar into the libs directory instead, didn't change anything.

As that didn't seem to work and the server complained about missing bundle headers I built a OSGI bundle that exported my CustomUserStoreManager Package (the source can be found on github as well, I'm not allowed to add more than two URLs) - now the bundle gets loaded and activated but nothing more. Still my class is nowhere to be seen. I don't see it as an available class in the User Store add dialog and I don't see it as an available class in the log config. No hint of it anywhere, not in the log files, not in the server's startup output. Nada.

Am I doing something wrong?

I have to add that I by no means am a Java developer nor a developer at all. I'm evaluating WSO2 for a customer and this is supposed to be a PoC. Once it works and I know that using PBKDF2 hashes are possible someone more competent is going to build a production version.

Thanks in advance,
SunTsu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 IS 5.3.0 is based on org.wso2.carbon.user.core 4.4.11 [[1]](https://github.com/SunTsu/wso2_custom_userstore/blob/master/pom.xml#L21) and you are using 4.2.0. Documentation should be updated in this case. You can find a sample code [[2]](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/isura/CustomUserStoreManager/) which is written for WSO2 IS 5.1.0 and article in [[3]](http://isurad.blogspot.com/2016/03/how-to-write-custom-user-store-manager.html).

Comment: Thank you. After changing my Bundle Activator to look like yours and using the appropriate org.wso2.carbon.user.core the CustomUserStoreManager class was recognized and could be added as User Store. Thank you for your help, very much appreciated.